# Search via Python Search API timing out intermittently

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api

We have an application that is basically just a form submission for requesting a team drive to be created. It's hosted on Google App Engine.

This timeout error is coming from a single field in the form that simply does typeahead for an email address. All of the names on the domain are indexed in the datastore, about 300k entities - nothing is being pulled directly from the directory api. After 10 seconds of searching (via the Python Google Search API), it will time out. This is currently intermittent, but errors have been increasing in frequency.

```
Error: line 280, in get_result raise _ToSearchError(e) Timeout: Failed to complete request in 9975ms
```

Essentially, speeding up the searches will resolve. I looked at the code and I don't believe there is any room for improvement there. I am not sure if increasing the instance class will improve this, it is currently an F2. Or if perhaps there is another way to improve the index efficiency. I'm not entirely sure how one would do that however. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Search Code:

```
class LookupUsersorGrpService(object):

    '''
    lookupUsersOrGrps accepts various params and performs  search

    ''' 
    def lookupUsersOrGrps(self,params):
        search_results_json = {}
        search_results = []
        directory_users_grps = GoogleDirectoryUsers()
        error_msg = 'Technical error'
        query = ''

        try:

            #Default few values if not present
            if ('offset' not in params) or (params['offset'] is None):      
                params['offset'] = 0
            else:
                params['offset'] = int(params['offset'])

            if ('limit' not in params) or (params['limit'] is None): 
                params['limit'] = 20
            else:
                params['limit'] = int(params['limit'])

            #Search related to field name
            query = self.appendQueryParam(q=query, p=params,  qname='search_name',  criteria=':',  pname='query', isExactMatch=True,splitString=True)

            #Search related to field email
            query = self.appendQueryParam(q=query, p=params,  qname='search_email',  criteria=':',  pname='query', isExactMatch=True, splitString=True)

            #Perform search
            log.info('Search initialized :\"{}\"'.format(query) )

            # sort results by name ascending
            expr_list = [search.SortExpression(expression='name', default_value='',direction=search.SortExpression.ASCENDING)]
            # construct the sort options
            sort_opts = search.SortOptions(expressions=expr_list)

            #Prepare the search index
            index = search.Index(name= "GoogleDirectoryUsers",namespace="1") 
            search_query = search.Query(
                    query_string=query.strip(),
                    options=search.QueryOptions(
                                limit=params['limit'],
                                offset=params['offset'],
                                sort_options=sort_opts,
                                returned_fields = directory_users_grps.get_search_doc_return_fields()
                                ))                
            #Execute the search query
            search_result = index.search(search_query)

            #Start collecting the values
            total_cnt = search_result.number_found
            params['limit'] = len(search_result.results)

            #Prepare the response object    
            for teamdriveDoc in search_result.results:
                teamdriveRecord = GoogleDirectoryUsers.query(GoogleDirectoryUsers.email==teamdriveDoc.doc_id).get()
                if teamdriveRecord:
                    if teamdriveRecord.suspended == False:
                        search_results.append(teamdriveRecord.to_dict())

            search_results_json.update({"users" : search_results})
            search_results_json.update({"limit" : params['limit'] if len(search_results)>0 else '0'})
            search_results_json.update({"total_count" : total_cnt if len(search_results)>0 else '0'})
            search_results_json.update({"status" : "success"})

        except Exception as e:
            log.exception("Error in performing search")
            search_results_json.update({"status":"failed"})
            search_results_json.update({"description":error_msg})             

        return search_results_json   



    ''' Retrieves the given param from dict and adds to query if exists    
    '''
    def appendQueryParam(self, q='', p=[], qname=None, criteria='=', pname=None, 
        isExactMatch = False, splitString = False, defaultValue=None):        

        if (pname in p) or (defaultValue is not None):
            if len(q) > 0:
                q += ' OR '
            q += qname 
            if criteria:
                q += criteria 

            if defaultValue is None:
                val = p[pname]
            else:
                val = defaultValue            

            if splitString:
                val = val.replace("", "~")[1: -1]

            #Helps to retain passed argument as it is, example email
            if isExactMatch:
                q +=  "\"" +val + "\""
            else:
                q +=  val

        return q
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Index instance's `search` method accepts a `deadline` parameter, so you could use that to increase the time that you are willing to wait for the search to respond:

`search_result = index.search(search_query, deadline=30)`

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/indexclass#instance-methods) doesn't specify acceptable value for `deadline`, but other App Engine services tend to accept values up to 60 seconds.